# Moving forward in history in GNU info

Tags: user-interface, info

The key bound to `(history-node)` lets GNU `info` jump to the last node visited in this window (like a browser's back button). Is there an opposite for this function in GNU `info`: a way to go forward again in the history if you have gone back (like a browser's forward button)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`history-node` [*pops* the most recently selected node](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info-stnd/html_node/Node-Commands.html), which means the history no longer contains that node; there is therefore no way to go “forward”.

There is another way of navigating the history though: `list-visited-nodes` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>) lists all the nodes in the current window’s history, and that can be used to navigate in the history: go to a node in the list, visit it, then `history-node` back to the list.